# Electrode potential

Tags: electrochemistry

In my book the definition of electrode potential was given when a metal rod is dipped into its own ion solution.there occurs either oxidation or reduction due to which a potential difference exists between electrode(metal rod) and solution on interface(on surface of metal) called electrode potential.. but is it necessary to dip the
metal rod  into its own ion solution. What will happen if we dip the metal into some other solution?will then the electrode potential of that metal be same if dipped this into some other solution?.

Comment: do you mean $E^\circ_\mathrm{red}$?

Comment: Both E° and E..

Comment: Standard hydrogen electrode does not use a dipped metallic hydrogen bar. Neither chinhydron electrode (used sonetimes for pH measurement before glass electrodes) uses a metal as the part of the redox system. Electrodes (as conductors) are sometimes just inert conductive materials, like platinum or glassy carbon, not participating in the redox process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

1. If the metallic electrode M is dipped into pure water or into a solution containing non-reactive metallic ions, like alkaline metals, the electrode potential is theoretically infinite during a couple of nanoseconds. But this does not last. Immediately after this time, one, two, three or several atoms M are oxidized by air or water. This produces a tiny amount of $\ce{M^{z+}}$ ions. As a consequence, both the concentration of $\ce{M^{z+}}$ ions and the electrode potential get to a finite value. The potential depends on the concentration of the $\ce{M^{z+}}$ ion according to Nernst's law.
2. If the metallic electrode M is dipped into a solution containing metallic ions $\ce{Y^{y+}}$ having a strong positive redox potential, the metallic electrode M is oxidized by these ions to produce $\ce{M^{z+}}$ ions and a deposit of metallic $\ce{Y}$ metal. If z = y = 2, the reaction is ; $$\ce{M  +  Y^{2+} ->  M^{2+} + Y}$$ In this case, the concentration of the ion $\ce{M^{2+}}$ is continuous increasing. The electrode potential of the electrode M is changing during the reaction. At the end of the reaction, the electrode potential is governed by Nernst's law.

Edit : The potential of an electrode dipping in pure water is not defined if the "solution" is totally pure water. Another way of saying it is to say that the potential is infinite if there is absolutely no ion of this electrode in solution. But it is practically impossible to get a solution with zero ion of the corresponding metal in solution. I repeat here Nernst's law :
$$\pu{E = E° + ( 0.059/2) log[M^{2+}]}$$
If [$\ce{M^{2+}}] = 0$, its log and the potential both tend to - ∞.

But if there is only ***one***(=$1$) ion $\ce{M^{2+}}$ in $1$ L water, its molar concentration is $\ce{[M^{2+}] = 1/(6·10^{23})}$, and the potential is not infinite as before. It becomes $$\ce{E = E° - (0.059/2)· log(6·10^{+ 23} ) = E° − 0.70 V}$$
If there are just $2$ ions $\ce{M^{2+}}$ in $1$ L water, its molar concentration is $\ce{[M^{2+}] = 2/(6·10^{23})}$, the potential becomes $$\ce{E = E° - (0.059/2)· log(3·10^{+ 23} ) = E° − 0.69 V}$$ This is not infinite !